# Is Acer Palmatum Diecious, Monoecious, or another variety of ecious?

Tags: botany, reproduction

I am compiling information about plants in my garden, and studying botany for interest, and was wondering if anyone knows whether Acer Palmatum (and more broadly Acers in general) are monoecious, diecious, etc.

I found some info stating that Acer Rubrum can be [either](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_rubrum#Description) [effectively](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2444057) but not sure for Acer Palmatum. I have not read the journal article yet admittedly, as I am looking for a way to access it that doesn't bust the bank.

Additionally, what is a good source for searching for this information, and other botanical info that might be slightly too niche or specific for general gardening practitioners?

Thanks in advance!